# How to create EReference list with upper bound of 1 in ecore

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, ecore

I have an EReference 'inputs' in ecore. I need this reference to be an Elist with an upper bound of one i.e. the maximum number of elements that this list contains is one element.

My problem is that when I set the upper bound property to '1' and generate model code the input ERefernce is no longer a EList of inputs, it just an 'input' object.

Its seems to me if you want an EReference to be a list you need to set the upper bound  property to be > 1 or else -1.

Is there any way I can accomplish this in ecore?

Comment: If you want an upper bound of 1 why do you want the EReference to use a list?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this within EMF. Think of `EList` as EMF's inner API, that you are not supposed to deal with.

Your list's size limit sounds like a validation detail, or a model constraint of the implementation.